# Selecting Threshhold from ROC curve

Tags: classification, python, roc

I plotted an ROC curve for a classification problem and I am looking a way to find out the threshold point for the left most top point - Highest TPR and low FPR. How do I do it in Python ?

Comment: The point of the ROC curve is that it tells you the *trade-offs* of each operating point. You can always detect more positives by lowering the threshold, but this comes with the cost of increasing the FPR (except for the trivial ROC with AUC=1). Picking the **highest TPR** is tautologically the same as choosing the point (1,1), because this is the point that detects all positives *at the cost of also retrieving all false positives*. Therefore, your description of the "top leftmost" point needs some clarification: what kind of a tradeoff do you want between TPR and FPR?

Comment: For example, one way to think about the ROC curve is the Youden's $J$ index, which measures the vertical distance from random classification to each operating point. A certain kind of trade-off is attained by choosing the point that maximizes $J$, maximizing $J$ isn't universally the best option because the tradeoff between TPR and FPR might not be appropriate for any particular task. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Youden%27s_J_statistic

Comment: I completely get your point but then how do I select the optimal threshold point ?

Comment: Unfortunately, there's no way to answer this other than saying that you choose the operating point that matches your needs -- I can't tell you what the trade-offs are, because I don't know the equities involved, and how I value the outcomes might differ from how you value them. You'll have to ask yourself how many FPRs are you willing to incur to achieve a certain level of TPR.

Comment: Thank you so much, your answer really helped me to arrive at conclusion that selecting threshold is completely subjective.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, there's no way to answer this other than saying that you choose the operating point that matches your needs -- I can't tell you what the trade-offs are, because I don't know the equities involved, and how I value the outcomes might differ from how you value them. You'll have to ask yourself how many FPRs are you willing to incur to achieve a certain level of TPR.

The point of the ROC curve is that it tells you the *trade-offs* of each operating point. You can always detect more positives by lowering the threshold, but this comes with the cost of increasing the FPR (except for the trivial ROC with AUC=1). Picking the *highest TPR* is tautologically the same as choosing the point (1,1), because this is the point that detects all positives *at the cost of also retrieving all false positives*. Therefore, your description of the "top leftmost" point needs some clarification: what kind of a tradeoff do you want between TPR and FPR?

For example, one way to think about the ROC curve is the [Youden's $J$ index](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Youden%27s_J_statistic), which measures the vertical distance from random classification to each operating point. A certain kind of trade-off is attained by choosing the point that maximizes $J$, maximizing $J$ isn't universally the best option because the tradeoff between TPR and FPR might not be appropriate for any particular task.